# How to load a JSON file into java that has unique name for each record?

Tags: java, json, gson

For example my JSON file look like this;

```
{
  "Test1": {
  "A": {},
  "B": "1",
  "C": "2",
  "D": "3"
 },
  "Test2": {
  "A": {},
  "B": "4",
  "C": "5",
  "D": "6"
 },
  "Test3": {
  "A": {},
  "B": "7",
  "C": "8",
  "D": "9"
 },
  "Test4": {
  "A": {},
  "B": "10",
  "C": "11",
  "D": "12"
 }

 ...
 ...
}
```

This would have been simple if the file only contained a few records, but in my case I'm dealing with thousands of records. For simpler version I've used gson library but not sure how I could load this JSON file which has unique name for each record into Java.

***************UPDATE*******************************

I now managed to read it raw and Map the data. However, still have a minor issue.

This is the code I used to Map

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
File jsonFile = new File(jsonFilePath);
        Map<String, Object> mapObject = mapper.readValue(jsonFile,
                new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
                });

System.out.println(mapObject.get("Test1"));
```

I'm getting below results, which is fine. However, not sure how I could obtain the data within "values" of the map.

> {A={}, B=1, C=2, D=3}

I tried below to re-map but it's failing as expected, because the keys no longer are surrounded by double quotes (see above)!

```
Map<String, Object> nestedObject = mapper.readValue(
                mapObject.get("Test1").toString(),
                new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
                });
```

Comment: Read it raw. Read it as a Map. Then you'll have a map of String to Object.

Comment: @Dan, thank you I'll have a go at your suggestion!

Comment: @DanTemple I've updated the question, please see if you could help. cheers

Comment: "I'm getting below results" --no, you dont. "System.out.println(mapObject.get("Test1");" will not compile.

Comment: @specializt, Thank you for pointing out! I retyped the code here, hence I missed the ')'. with that exception it did print the result as shown above!

Comment: Why can't you just get the nested Map and cast?

Comment: This is a classical bad JSON design, but you have to live with it.  The outermost layer maps to a Map, and then you must iterate through the Map, extract the key and associated inner Map, then construct a new Map that incorporates the key as an attribute (eg, "name"), and store that map into a List.  So the elements of the list would be something like `{ "name" : "Test4", "A": {}, "B": "10", "C": "11", "D": "12" }`

Comment: @HotLicks, thank you for the suggestion, which appears to be a doable and a solution that should work. It's a shame I will need to reconstruct the data as you have stated not well designed JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

If you know your objects all contain the same keys A, B, C and D then you could create a *class* that maps a single object

```
class MyEntry {
  /**
   * You've tagged the question "gson" but your example code uses Jackson so I've
   * written this class with Jackson annotations rather than Gson ones.
   */
  @JsonProperty("A")
  public Object a; // or a more specific type if you know one

  @JsonProperty("B")
  public String b;

  @JsonProperty("C")
  public String c;

  @JsonProperty("D")
  public String d;
}
```

and then unmarshal the JSON as a `Map<String, MyEntry>`

```
Map<String, MyEntry> mapObject = mapper.readValue(jsonFile,
    new TypeReference<Map<String, MyEntry>>() {
    });

System.out.println(mapObject.get("Test1").b); // prints 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It's not simple as A,B,C,D as I have unknown records (over 1000). For simpler one I have used gson (above example is implemented in Jackson but originally I was using gson for other jobs) to implement a class to parse the JSON file. But the data file was given to me is not well nested I guess!